# How to create an URL shortcut for Linux in Python?

Tags: python, url

As you see in the question, I am trying to create an URL shortcut in Python for both Windows and Linux.

Windows shortcut is working, this is my code if somebody needs it :

```py
import os

target = "www.google.com"
with open(os.path.join(shortcut_path, "windows_shortcut.url"), "w") as f:
   f.write('[InternetShortcut]\n')
   f.write('URL=%s' % target)
```

But for Linux it is an other problem and I can't find any solution which is working for me with google.

This is what I tried :

```py
import os

target = "www.google.com"
with open(os.path.join(shortcut_path, "linux_shortcut.url"), "w") as f:
    f.write("""[Desktop Entry]
    Encoding=UTF-8
    Name=Link to google              
    Type=Link
    URL=%s
    Icon=text-html
    Name[en_US]=commit""" % target)
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try naming it `linux_shortcut.desktop`

Comment: This was the solution, thank you

Comment: Instead of editing, add an answer to your question with the solution and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem is quite easy btw, just replace `linux_shortcut.url` by `linux_shortcut.desktop`